# Passing arrays to new php-script or execute in the same function (execution time)

Tags: php, post, execution-time

I am currently working on a project with some more data than in other projects.
I filter different rss-feeds and save them in our database (we already contacted the authors and they are okay with that ;) ). We already gathered some data and the script takes about 8 to 10 seconds to finish. The script is called by a cron-job every 5 Minutes.
The articles from the feeds are about different artists, and the system checks which artists it is.

Now we want to add a system, where the user can subscribe to different artists and gets an email when a new article is saved in the database. So my idea was to simply pass the id's from the articles that are new to a new function where we handle the Sending of the Mails.

Now I am afraid that the execution time gets to high if we get more and more data. 
So I have two questions:
How do you get the time for the execution time of the php script? Is it the time the server needs to execute the whole php file or the different single functions?

I thought it's maybe better to pass the id's to a new file an execute a new script, so the execution time does not get to high.
If so, which is the best way to pass the data to a new file and execute the script.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The new file concept is best suite in your application. We able to pass separate id's on every time to separate page and we can get result easily.

So, we can use Ajax and we can show loader icon up to result comes.

Comment: I cant use ajax because (as i said above) the script is executed by the server via "php"-command. So I have to use php only

Answer (score 0):

Get the time in unix time stamp at the very top of the script right after the php open tag by calling 
`date("U");` and then call it again at the very end of your script when you are doing whatever your script does. You can now subtract the first timestamp from the second and you are left with the execution time in seconds. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php if you want to get a more fine-tuned execution time and use microseconds or the like.

If it is a very short running script, you can use microtime instead of date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: Oh sorry...the question was not how in terms of php functions but if the execution time is one complete file or a single function.

Comment: From the server's point of view, the execution time is  the time it takes to execute the php process - which would be the entire file, plus compiling it to opcode and running it. If you are creating your own function - you can measure both. Hope  that helps. Was trying to answer what you said: "So I have two questions: How do you get the time for the execution time of the php script? Is it the time the server needs to execute the whole php file or the different single functions?"

Comment: Okay, like i expected. Do you think its okay to set the execution time really high to make sure, that the server has enough time to execute the script?